# Cannot use OracleParameter of type NVarChar with ParameterDirection of Output when calling stored procedure from ADO.NET

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am using ADO.Net to call a stored procedure in an Oracle database. The stored procedure has an out parameter that is a NVARCHAR2. Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE VALIDATE_Bin ( 
machine_dump_name IN NVARCHAR2, 
lpn               IN NVARCHAR2, 
result            OUT NUMBER, 
message           OUT NVARCHAR2) 
IS 
BEGIN 
    IF lpn LIKE 'A%' THEN 
      result := 1; 
      message := NULL; 
    ELSE 
      IF lpn IS NULL THEN 
        result := 0; 
        message := 'Failed Read'; 
      ELSE 
        result := 0; 
        message := 'Invalid Barcode'; 
      END IF; 
    END IF; 
END;
```

And here is the c# code to fill in the parameters of the command:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("machine_dumper_name",OracleType.NVarChar){Value = "My Dumper"});
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("lpn", OracleType.NVarChar) { Value ="XYZ1234"});
var resultParam = new OracleParameter("result", OracleType.Number) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
command.Parameters.Add(resultParam);
var messageParam = new OracleParameter("message", OracleType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
command.Parameters.Add(messageParam);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If I execute it like this I get the exception:

> System.Exception: Parameter 'message': No size set for variable length data type: String.

No worries I think. Oracle expects a string length on the "message" parameter. So I add a size parameter on the "message" parameter:

```
var messageParam = new OracleParameter("message", OracleType.NVarChar, 255) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
```

and then when I run it I get this System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'VALIDATE_Bin'

How the heck am I supposed to call this procedure and get the message out? I think this problem is specific to string data types. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Kindly try the below                                                      var messageParam = new OracleParameter("message", OracleType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}{Value = ""};

Comment: No go. I tried "" , DBNull.Value,  " " and they all result in  PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Comment: Try changing message out nvarchar2 to message out nvarchar

Comment: @psaraj12 that doesn't work either, and if that was the only way to get it working i would be very surprised! There seems to be an underlying problem with the way the OracleClient handles the out parameters.

Comment: I have found a work-around to this problem, and that is using the OleDbConnection instead, and prefixing the connection string with "Provider=OraOLEDB;" I'm still looking for an answer though. How do I register a bug in the System.Data.OracleClient library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading one of @psaraj12's comments I realized the problem parameter may not be the "message" parameter after all. After eliminating variables from the stored procedure one by one I discovered a mis-match in parameter names. In the procedure:

```
machine_dump_name IN NVARCHAR2,
```

and in the C# code:

```
new OracleParameter("machine_dumper_name",OracleType.NVarChar)
```

Thank you for all your ideas everyone! When I used the actual name of the parameter (machine_DUMP_name) everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var messageParam = new OracleParameter("message", OracleDbType.NVarchar2,UInt16.MaxValue) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
messageParam.Value = DbNull.Value
```

Comment: same error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call.  Like I said, I tried every permutation, but it seems that there is a bug in the System.Data.OracleClient assembly.

Comment: Try setting the value explicitly to DbNull.Value